# Using php generated link for searching in eCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

is there any way to search in eCommerce products shop using button from separate php page?

Cheers

Comment: Hi yes, that is possible but your question is too broad. Please post some works you have done and go back here to ask help if your having trouble.

Comment: Hi thre, first of all thank you for your reply.

Comment: What I would like to archive is having something like a photo gallery and each photo after zooming is gonna contain a button to search for that item in eCommerce shop. Because I have almost zero experience with wordpress - it's honestly more efficient to me make that whole gallery on separate php page and I wanted to make sure that it is even possible to do so. Gallery is gonna be static because I have only few images to post once a year and there is no sense to make that dynamic. Otherwise whole wordpress including plugins is bought.

Comment: So the idea is to have "cards" containg something as a hidden keyword which is gonna be used lately for that button. Now the question is what that link to eCommerce containg hidden card keyword should look like or if this is not the way it works.

Comment: Hi Martin your idea is possible. You really need to save a certain information or let your user input data for that field and create some script that will query database on the inputted string and the data being saved in the database. I couldn't give you scripts but that is the idea.

Comment: So isn't there any way how to access that exact search bar that is in my eCommerce product list?  I mean to use that bar to let it do database queries for me using my keyword.

Comment: You might want to use this http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/ if you are using woocommmerce. In woocommerce you could also try to read and apply this one https://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and suggestions. I will definitely have a look on that. Even though it's on local server atm, would not this work on hosted server as well ? 
http://localhost:81/wordpress/?s=KEYWORD&post_type=product